# Linked jQuery script from Cloudflare CDN throws CSP error in console on "sub-include" underscore-min.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, content-security-policy

Currently I have:

```
<script rel="preload" as="script" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

And I've got my CSP rule set up:

```
add_header Content-Security-Policy: "default-src 'self' https:; script-src 'self' 'sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=';";
```

But I'm receiving the following error in the Chrome Console:

> Refused to load the script 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8='". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

How do I fix this? Do I need to explicitly include `underscore-min.js` (and any additional "sub-included" dependencies) inside my html document? Am I able to whitelist all scripts from `cdnjs.cloudflare.com` instead?

Thanks!

**Edit:** Here's a screenshot of the console error which appears to be happening in the `jquery.min.js` file.

[image: Console Error]

Additionally, not sure if this is relevant, but I'm getting `Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive ':'` with the https: part of the rule that I found in some Google devtools article or somewhere else. But I guess the colon is invalid for CSP rules in nginx?

**Edit 2:** Okay, so after more research and experimentation I've learned more about CSP and from what I've read, I may be encountering a FireFox only issue. I'm now receiving the following error, even with no CSP rule defined:

> Content Security Policy: Ignoring “'unsafe-inline'” within script-src: ‘strict-dynamic’ specified

The closest I've come to a working solution is by whitelisting all the domains I need to load from:

```
add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com https://ssl.google-analytics.com https://www.google.com https://www.gstatic.com; img-src 'self' data: https://ssl.google-analytics.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com https://fonts.googleapis.com; font-src 'self' https://themes.googleusercontent.com; frame-src https://www.google.com; object-src 'none';";
```

Yes, I am aware that I have `'unsafe-inline'` present in both my `script-src` and `style-src` rules, in an attempt to get the website working in FireFox. If the website no longer renders or functions properly in FireFox because of a bug with FF's CSP implementation (needing confirmation), then the purpose of CSP is secondary and therefore irrelevant (until this bug awaiting confirmation has been fixed).

Since it seems there's relatively limited info on CSP at the time of writing, can anyone shed some light on why FireFox appears to be forcing `'strict-dynamic'` into the CSP rules, despite it not being present anywhere in the rule definition? Is it implied or otherwise appended by FireFox's interpretation of (part of) my current CSP rule?

Thank you for your help.

And for anyone else reading up on CSP, take a look into https://cspvalidator.org/ which can help you debug your own CSP rules. I know it's helped me!

Comment: What do you mean by "sub-include"? How are you requesting the file that is different than jQuery?

Comment: *I'm* not requesting that file at all. It's a dependency of jQuery it would seem.

Comment: Have you tried a different jQuery CDN? Maybe try the one from jQuery directly? https://code.jquery.com/

Comment: Nope. Otherwise show me in the source. It may be part of a plugin or some other thing you're loading, but it isn't jQuery loading it.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I've added a screenshot of the console error to my question.

Comment: So go to [the source](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js") in a new tab/window, hit CTRL-F, and search for `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js`. It isn't there. If you don't believe me, go the jQuery website yourself, look at the unminified source code. The only dependency is the Sizzle engine (which is a completely stand-alone library). Something just is not lining up.

Comment: I can confirm what you are saying, but it doesn't answer why jquery.min.js is the source file of the console error. Do you have any insight as to why this is the case in the screenshot I uploaded?

Comment: It is probably Rocket Loader - disable it on CloudFlare and see if the problem resolves itself.

Comment: Didn't know that was a thing, but negatory, I have verified it is off for the domain I'm working on.

Comment: @Chad - all out of answers. without fully understanding the server environment, what plugins or browser extensions are being used, etc. etc. I'm all out of guesses.

Comment: I have resolved the issue, and it's because FireFox does not play nicely with `rel="preload"` link and script elements. I will post a more detailed answer to this question soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any lurkers without resolve, I have isolated the issue to be with how FireFox currently handles the `rel="preload"`attribute. It does not play nicely to say the least, and I assume the same of Edge.

**TL;DR:** Do not use `rel="preload"` until it is handled more uniformly across major browsers. Additionally, my question was using jQuery from the CloudFlare CDN, and the point of a CDN is to prevent visitors from (pointlessly) downloading the same content over and over. In other words, not only does `rel="preload"` act differently between flagship browsers, it's rendered superfluous because the point of a CDN is that the visitor will have *already downloaded the given file(s)* when visiting previous websites that also use the same file from the same CDN.

[Click here](https://www.keycdn.com/img/blog/preload-browser-support.webp) to see an overview of current browser support for `rel="preload"`.

---

**Findings**

Chrome and perhaps other browsers are handling resources to be preloaded (more) correctly, though overall we seem to be lacking tools and documentation on how to get up and running with CSP *correctly*, and hopefully this answer will give some insight to others who are relatively new to CSP like myself.

There are a number of issues I've observed when troubleshooting my CSP rules. One of these is that pairing the `as` attribute to typehint may work against you with the current browser implementations of CSP. For example, I was trying to load a Google font with `as="font"` present, which if I recall correctly caused additional headaches until it was set to be `as="style"` instead. What I've gathered (please chime in / edit this answer if you can verify otherwise) is that this is because the linked resource is indeed a stylesheet instead of a font file.

Another strange point I encountered is that when you are preloading a resource, you have to actually 'initialize' the given resource after it has been loaded. So your choices are to either clone the `<link>` element with the desired `rel="stylesheet/script/etc"` (which is in direct opposition to the DRY principle), or to attach an onload event to the `<link>` element (which doesn't go against DRY, but *does* feel pretty archaic. It's 2019! Why can't our browser do this for us? Or perhaps we could add browser support for something like an `append="true"` attribute that would automatically and *gracefully* handle this for us).

I will lift the following paragraph and code snippet from [the following GitHub project](https://github.com/filamentgroup/loadCSS) to better explain the `onload` "solution" (which does **not** work in FireFox due to the CSP errors I documented in this question):

> In browsers that support it, the `rel=preload` attribute will cause the browser to *fetch* the stylesheet, but it will not **apply** the CSS once it is loaded (it merely fetches it). To address this, **we recommend using an onload attribute on the link that will apply the CSS when it finishes loading.**

```
<link rel="preload" href="path/to/mystylesheet.css" as="style" onload="this.rel='stylesheet'">
```

As stated, this feels very archaic. We should not have to choose between redundant vs. archaic code.

I mentioned that Chrome seems to have a better production implementation of CSP, but there is still some work to be done. Additionally, the reason I wound up on this wild witch-hunt was (naturally) I was working to improve the speed and performance of a website, so I was using the Chrome Inspector's Lightouse / Audit tool. Well, from all the testing I conducted, it would appear that resources we should expect to be already cached on a client's computer (Bootstrap, jQuery, Google Fonts, etc.) are purged prior to performing an audit and are redownloaded to be accounted for in the generated report. This is fine (I understand this to be the desired behavior); however, if we had a radiobox as developers to *override* the clearing of shared resources via CDNs when performing our audits, I believe the developer would have an added level of insight to their website's performance. Or at least differentiate in the report to show exactly how much time was spent downloading and initializing linked resources.

These dependencies don't stop at `rel="preload"`. When I was troubleshooting, I tried alternate values in some cases such as `rel="connect"` on the first resource I was linking to served via CloudFlare's CDN. When conducting research on the topic, I found [the following article](https://www.keycdn.com/blog/resource-hints) with this information:

> The final resource hint we want to talk about is preconnect. Preconnect allows the browser to **setup early connections before an HTTP request is actually sent to the server**. This includes DNS lookups, TLS negotiations, TCP handshakes. This in turn eliminates roundtrip latency and saves time for users.
>
> “Preconnect is an important tool in your optimization toolbox… it can eliminate many costly roundtrips from your request path - in some cases reducing the request latency by hundreds and even thousands of milliseconds. - Ilya Grigorik”

But, unshockingly, `preconnect` performed similarly in browsers that do not support `preload`. And it's easy to get this all mixed up when you think the issue is with your CSP rules, not with your markup.

I hope this provides some context and helps alleviate some frustration regarding CSP and the current (lack of) proper implementation of it in major browsers to date. Please feel free to edit this answer to improve it or to add more context and information to the benefit of our fellow developers.